# Update MySQL Table using CSV file

Tags: php, mysql, csv

my Current MySQL table `employee_data` has 13k rows with 17 columns. The data in the table came from a CSV file `Employees.csv`. after importing my csv data I added a new column 'password' (so its not in the csv file) Password is edited and accessed via a web portal. I now have an updated csv file and I want to update my main table with that data but I don't want to lose my password info.

Should I import my new CSV file into a temp table in my database and some how compare them?  I am not sure where to start and I am open to recommendations.

**I am now realizing  I should have kept my password info in a separate table. Doh!**

I guess I could created a php file that compares each row based on the employee_id field but with 13k rows I am afraid it would time out possibly.

Comment: have you tried tools like MySQL workbench ?

Comment: I have not but will look into them now.

Comment: Are you asking for code or query tool?

Comment: I think the easiest thing would be to get the mysql query (code) that would compare and update what is needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would do it like this :

- Create a [temp table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) using `CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;` syntax
- use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) to import the data from the CSV into the table
- Use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) to update the primary table using a primary key / unique column (perhaps `employee_id`)

I have worked with tables containing 120 million lines and imported CSV files containing 30 million lines into it - this is the method I use all of the time - much more efficient than anything in PHP (and thats my server side language of choice)

Comment: I think this is the option I am going to try first. Thanks.

Comment: I do the same thing every day with multiple 60GB files...this is always the cleanest/safest way to get it done

Comment: Before, I thought maybe this is not a good idea for daily update, as it needs to create some temp table in the database server. But it is true this is the easiest way comparing to use php to update the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try other tools other than php based ones *phpMyAdmin* 
[MySQL workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) is a great tool, 
based on you connection it will take a while to query the database with your data.

There are workarounds with php timeout limit, 
[set_time_limit();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)